# Kentico 9 sync 401 when target is AD auth

Tags: web-config, kentico

How can I avoid the 401 error, access denied, when i try to preform  sync from one environment to another? I think there is an edit to the web.config that will allow this, but I am not sure what I need. I came across the same question in DevNet, but there wasn't an answer. https://devnet.kentico.com/questions/content-staging-windows-authentication-problem.

Answer (score 1):

I got this to work. Sync points to /CMSPages/Staging/SyncServer.asmx. In IIS, I adjusted the Authentication on CMSPages. I enabled Anonymous, and disabled Windows Auth.

I did this on my DEV instance, and i'm syncing from PROD. So far, so good.

Answer (score 0):

Did you set up the Staging user / credentials properly on the target and set them properly on the source site?

Is staging enabled on the target server?

Does both environments have Full Access/Control with their app pool processor?

Is it only some tasks or all tasks that you get this?

Is basic authentication also allowed on the sites (may be needed, but unsure on that)

Comment: Everything worked until i enabled windows auth in IIS. Let me also enable basic Auth and see what happens.

Comment: Sounds good, i have a feeling it may be required since it authenticates either with a matching username/password (seperate from the Users), or the X-code which may operate based on the basic auth.